# Alert is not displayed in TableViewController

Tags: swift, tableview, uialertview

The alert is not getting displayed, but it calls the code.

`TableViewController` is static and multiple section.

When I click the save Button , if my textfield is empty.

It has to show alert.

It is going through else block, only alert  is not get displayed.

Complete code of my method :

```
 @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let ndx = IndexPath(row:0, section: 0)
    var counter:Int = 0
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: ndx) as! TableViewCell
    let locationNameCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row:1, section: 0)) as! TableViewCell
        let shoppingDetails = ShoppingDetails(context:managedContext)
        let storeName =  cell.storeName.text!
        let storeFlag  =  validateShoppingList(storeName: storeName)
        if storeFlag == true {
            print("1111 storeFlag = \(storeFlag)")
            while counter < sectionRowCount {
                let item = IndexPath(row:counter, section: 1)
                let itemcell:TableViewCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: item) as! TableViewCell
                let list = shoppingDetails.shoppingToList?.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableSet
                let listDetails = ListDetails(context:managedContext)
                if itemcell.listItem.text! == "" {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "TrackActivity", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Default action"), style: .default, handler: nil))
                    alert.message = "Please Enter Item(s) Name"
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                listDetails.listItem = itemcell.listItem.text!
                listDetails.qty = Int64(itemcell.qtytextfield.text!)!
                listDetails.units = itemcell.unitstextfield.text!
                listDetails.isChecked = false

                list.add(listDetails)
                shoppingDetails.addToShoppingToList(list)
                counter = counter + 1
            }
            shoppingDetails.storeName = storeName
            shoppingDetails.location = locationNameCell.locationName.text!
            shoppingDetails.initialLetter = (cell.storeName.text!).first?.description
            let seqNo:Int = ShoppingDetails.getSeqNo(managedObjectContext: managedContext) + 1
            shoppingDetails.seqNo =  Int32(seqNo)
            coreData.saveContext()
            let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StoreDisplayController") as! StoreDisplayController
            vc.managedContext = managedContext
            vc.coreData = coreData
            vc.storeName = cell.storeName.text!
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
        } else {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "TrackActivity", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Default action"), style: .default, handler: nil))
            if storeFlag == false {
                alert.message = "Please Enter Store Name"
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

    }
```

Please provide your input on this.

Comment: What you mean by TableViewController is static, show your complete code to understand scenario, no issue in above code if  `storeFlag` is false then alert will be shown.

Comment: storeFlag is false. Then alert is not showing. I have multiple section in the Tableviewcontroller. Is that problem

Comment: you give us way too little information.. from your code, only thing we can deduce why the alert would not present is that if `storeFlag` is true

Comment: @BoR- multiple section never be a problem in it, may be an issue in calling the function in which `alert` is showing, to get exact issue show your complete code.

Comment: Maybe you are presenting `TableViewController` and presenting a controller over a presented controller can be a problem. Not sure though. Share more information please

Comment: remove `if storeFlag == false` - it is already in the `else` block of the opposite condition, it's completely redundant

Comment: @Umair Aamir May be , Thats the scenario what I have to do for displaying alerts

Comment: @Milan Nosáľ Yes I have removed and checked .Still alert is not getting displayed

Comment: @BoR- You are pushing the controller to another after showing the alert `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)` thats way it is not showing because `alert` presented to current controller & you moved to next controller.

Comment: yeah I know, but your question still misses a lot of context. it seems that the if block is completely useless for debugging (since you claim the else block executes).. the question here is if the whole `self` is properly presented, etc.

Comment: @BoR- issue with the `while counter < sectionRowCount` statement, what is the value of `sectionRowCount`, because if the loop runs multiple time then UI of app will get hanged and nothing will happen.

Comment: @Rocky sectionRowCount Value is 1 Now. But Maximum of 20.But that code is not called.Because the flag is false

Comment: Thanks @Rocky . Some Problem Counter.When I moved my code to the top ,alert works.

Answer (score 1):

In case, `saveButton` action is written in a custom uitableviewcell
alert view not present

please make sure `saveButton` written in main view

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way of using `AlertController` is

```
class MYAlertController: UIAlertController {

    var alertWindow: UIWindow?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        alertWindow?.isHidden = true
        alertWindow = nil
    }

    func show(animated: Bool = true) {
        alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        alertWindow?.rootViewController = UIViewController()

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window {
            alertWindow?.tintColor = window?.tintColor
        }

        alertWindow?.windowLevel = UIApplication.shared.windows.last!.windowLevel + 1
        alertWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        alertWindow?.rootViewController?.present(self, animated: animated, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Use this class to show alerts

**Usage**

```
func showAlert(_ title: String?,
                   message: String?,
                   actions: AlertActions,
                   style: UIAlertControllerStyle? = .alert) {
        var preferredStyle = style
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom != .phone {
            preferredStyle = .alert
        }

        let alertController = MYGOAlertController(title: title,
                                                  message: message,
                                                  preferredStyle: preferredStyle!)
        for action in actions {
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: action.title,
                                                    style: action.style,
                                                    handler: action.actionHandler))
        }
        alertController.show()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. What I have to pass for actions type

Comment: I have tried this code still  alert is not getting displayed